# Why typecasting between char *ptr to int and int *ptr to char works completely fine? when they are designed to point to specific datatyped variables

Tags: c, pointers

I have just started learning pointers. I have some questions regarding pointers typecasting. Consider below program.

```
int main(){
   int a = 0xff01;
   char *s  = &a;
   char *t = (int *) &a;
   printf("%x",*(int *)s);
   printf(" %x",*(int *)t);
   return 0;
}
```

The statement `char *s = &a` gives

`warning: incompatible pointer conversion type.`

But noticed that the two `printf()` statements works fine they give me the right output. The question is

```
char *t , char *s  both are pointers to character type.
```

Why does 'C' compilers lets me to assign integer variable to char *p ? why dont they raise an error and restrict the programmer?

We have int *ptr to point to integer variables, then why do they still allow programmer to make char *ptr point to integer variable?

```
 // Another sample code
 char s = 0x02; 
 int *ptr = (char *)&s;
 printf("%x",*(char *)ptr); // prints the right output
```

Why does an int *ptr made point to character type? it works. why compiler dont restrict me?

I really think this leads me to confusion. If the pointer types are interchangeable with a typecast then what is the point to have two different pointers `char *ptr , int *ptr ?`
when we could retrieve values using `(int *) or (char *)`.

All pointers are of same size 4bytes(on 32bite machine). Then one could use `void pointer`.

Yes people told me, void pointers always needs typecasting when retrieving values from memory. When we know the type of variable we go for that specific pointer which eliminates the use of casting.

```
int a = 0x04;
int *ptr = &a;
void *p = &a;
printf("%x",*ptr); // does not require typecasting.
printf("%x",*(int *)p); // requires typecasting.
```

Yes, I have read that back in old days char *ptrs played role of void pointers. Is this one good reason? why still compilers support typecasting between pointers? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "works" doesn't mean what you think. It doesn't actually mean anything. "Works fine", however, is usually a sign of complete misunderstanding :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling with GCC 4.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.5, using this mildly modified version of your code (different definition of `main()` so it compiles with my preferred compiler options, and included `<stdio.h>` which I assume was omitted for brevity in the question — nothing critical) in file `ptr.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0xff01;
    char *s  = &a;
    char *t = (int *) &a;
    printf("%x",*(int *)s);
    printf(" %x",*(int *)t);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the compilation errors:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror ptr.c -o ptr  
ptr.c: In function ‘main’:
ptr.c:6:15: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
    char *s  = &a;
               ^
ptr.c:7:14: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
    char *t = (int *) &a;
              ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

So, both assignments are the source of a warning; my compilation options turn that into an error.

All pointers other than `void *` are typed; they point to an object of a particular type.  Void pointers don't point to any type of object and must be cast to a type before they can be dereferenced.

In particular, `char *` and `int *` point to different types of data, and even when they hold the same address, they are not the same pointer.  Under normal circumstances (most systems, most compilers — but there are probably exceptions if you work hard enough, but you're unlikely to be running into one of them)…as I was saying, under normal circumstances, the types `char *` and `int *` are not compatible because they point to different types.

Given:

```
int data = 0xFF01;
int *ip = &data;
char *cp = (char *)&data;
```

the code would compile without complaint.  The `int data` line is clearly unexceptional (unless you happen to have 16-bit `int` types — but I will assume 32-bit systems).  The `int *ip` line assigns the address of `data` to `ip`; that is assigning a pointer to `int` to a pointer to `int`, so no cast is necessary.

The `char *cp` line forces the compiler's hand to treat the address of `data` as a `char` pointer.  On most modern systems, the value in `cp` is the same as the value in `ip`.  On the system I learned C on (ICL [Perq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PERQ)), the value of a `char *` address to a memory location was different from the 'anything else pointer' address to the same memory location.  The machine was word-oriented, and byte-aligned addresses had extra bits set in the high end of the address. (This was in the days when the expansion of memory from 1 MiB to 2 MiB made a vast improvement because 750 KiB were used by the O/S, so we actually got about 5 times as much memory after as before for programs to use!  Gigabytes and gibibytes were both fantasies, whether for disk or memory.)

Your code is:

```
int a = 0xff01;
char *s  = &a;
char *t = (int *) &a;
```

Both the assignments have an `int *` on the RHS.  The cast in the second line is superfluous; the type of `&a` is `int *` both before and after the cast.  Assigning an `int *` to a `char *` is a warnable offense — hence the compiler warned.  The types are different.  Had you written `char *t = (char *)&a;`, then you would have gotten no warning from the compiler.

The printing code works because you take the `char *` values that were assigned to `s` and `t` and convert them back to the original `int *` before dereferencing them.  This will usually work; the standard guarantees it for conversions to `void *` (instead of `char *`), but in practice it will normally work for `anything *` where anything is an object type, not a function type.  (You are not guaranteed to be able to convert function pointers to data pointers and back again.)

Comment: So the standard gaurantees that conversion between data type pointers would work? so a pointer to float can point to integer and vice cersa with conversion?

Comment: More or less.  The details are in section 6.3.2.3 Pointers (subsection of section 6.3 Conversions).  Within broad limits, yes you can convert between different pointer types (where the target of both types is an object type, or the target of both is a function type).  There are caveats about 'correctly aligned', but if those requirements are met, round-tripping (from `A*` to `B*` and back to `A*`) will produce the original value.  Access via the converted type is more dubious unless the target type is a variant of `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

> The statement `char *s = &a` gives
>
> ```
> warning: incompatible pointer conversion type.
> ```

In this case, the warning indicates a *constraint violation*: A compiler must complain and may refuse to compile. For initialization (btw, a declaration is not a statement), the same conversion rules as for assignment apply, and there is no implicit conversion from `int *` to `char *` (or the other way round). That is, an explicit cast is required:

```
char *s = (char *)&a;
```

> Why do C compilers let me assign an integer variable to `char *p`? Why don’t they raise an error and restrict the programmer?

Well, you’ve got a warning. At the very least, a warning means you must understand why it is there before you ignore it. And as said above, in this case a compiler *may* refuse to compile.<sup>*)</sup>

> We have `int *ptr` to point to integer variables, then why do they still allow programmer to make `char *ptr` point to integer variable?

Pointers to a character type are special, they are allowed to point to objects of every type. That you’re allowed to do so, doesn’t mean it’s a good idea, the cast is required to keep you from doing such a conversion accidently. For pointer-to-pointer conversions in general, see below.

> ```
> int *ptr = (char *)&s;
> ```

Here, `ptr` is of type `int *`, and is initialized with a value of type `char *`. This is, again, a constraint violation.

> ```
> printf("%x",*(char *)ptr); // prints the right output
> ```

If a conversion from a pointer to another is valid, the conversion back also is and always yields the original value.

> If the pointer types are interchangeable with a typecast then what is the point to have two different pointers `char *ptr`, `int *ptr`?

Types exist to save you from errors. Casts exist to give you a way to tell the compiler that you know what you’re doing.

> All pointers are of same size 4bytes(on 32bite machine). Then one could use `void` pointer.

That’s true for many architectures, but quite not for all the C standard addresses. Having only `void` pointers would be pretty useless, as you cannot really do anything with them: no arithmetic, no dereferencing.

> Yes, I have read that back in old days `char *ptrs` played role of `void` pointers. Is this one good reason?

Perhaps a reason. (If a good one, is another question…)

---

When pointer-to-pointer conversions are allowed:

C11 (N1570) 6.3.2.3 p7

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned<sup>×)</sup> for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.
>
> <sup>×)</sup> In general, the concept “correctly aligned” is transitive: if a pointer to type `A` is correctly aligned for a pointer to type `B`, which in turn is correctly aligned for a pointer to type `C`, then a pointer to type `A` is correctly aligned for a pointer to type `C`.

Pointers to character types and pointers to `void`, as mentioned above, are always correctly aligned (and so are `int8_t` and `uint8_t` if they exist). There are platforms, on which a conversion from an arbitrary `char` pointer to an `int` pointer may violate alignment restrictions and cause a crash if executed.

If a converted pointer satisfies alignment requirements, this does not imply that it’s allowed to dereference that pointer, the only guarantee is that it’s allowed to convert it back to what it originally pointed to. For more information, look for strict-aliasing; in short, this means you’re not allowed to access an object with an expression of the wrong type, the only exception being the character types.

---

<sup>*)</sup> I don’t know the reasons in your particular case, but as an example, where it’s useful to give implementations such latitude in how to treat ill-formed programmes, see for example object-pointer-to-function-pointer conversions: They are a constraint violation (so they require a diagnostic message from the compiler) but are valid on POSIX systems (which guarantess well-defined semantics for such conversions). If the C standard required a conforming implementation to abort compilation, POSIX had to contradict ISO C (cf. POSIX `dlsym` for an example why these conversions can be useful), which it explicitly doesn’t intend to.

Comment: There's a lot of good in your answer, but I'm stuck on your use of _constraint violation_ in your first paragraph.  Are you sure that it is a constraint violation?  For comparison, look at §6.4.4 Constants, where there is an explicit section marked 'Constraints' and a subsequent section marked 'Semantics'.  I see no specification of 'Constraints' in §6.3.2.3 Pointers, which you quote. (The footnote is numbered 68 in ISO/IEC 9899:2011, but your quote is otherwise accurate for the standard as well as the draft you cite.) Also, POSIX and `dlsym()` is a rather complex area — to be polite about it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Thanks for proof-reading my post! Yes, my quotes are indeed confusing, I added the footnote to at least try to illustrate why the C standard is as permissive as it is, and I couldn't come up with a better example than object-pointer to function-pointer conversion. OP asks several times why her C compilers are that permissive and I wanted to give at least one example why the C standard allows this.

Comment: For my use of "constraint violation" in the first paragraph, that's addressed in 6.5.4 p3 "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast." and 6.5.16.1 [too long to quote here] says which conversions need a cast, in a constraints section.

Answer (score -3):

Pointers are not having any types, types described with pointer in program actually means that to which kind of data pointer is pointing. Pointers will be of same size.

When you write,

```
char *ptr;
```

it means that is is pointer to character type data and when dereferenced, it will fetch one bytes data from memory
Similarly,

```
double *ptr;
```

is pointer to double type data. So when you dereference, they will fetch 8 bytes starting from the location pointed by pointer.

Now remember that all the pointer are of 4 bytes on 32 bit machines irrespective of the type of data to which it is pointing. So if you store integer variable's address to a pointer which is pointing to character, it is completely legal and if you dereference it, it will get only one byte from memory. That is lowest byte of integer on little endian pc and highest byte of integer on big endian pc.

Now you are type casting your pointer to int type explicitly. So while dereferencing it will get while integer and print it. There is nothing wrong with this and this is how pointers work in c.

In your second example you are doing the same. Assigning address of character type variable to pointer which is pointing to integer. Again you are type casting pointer to character type so by dereference it will get only one byte from that location which is your character.

And frankly speaking, i dont know any practical usage of void pointer but as far as i know, void pointers are used when many type of data is to be dereferenced using a single pointer.

Consider that you want to store an integer variable's address to pointer. So you will declare pointer of integer type. Now later in program there is a need to store a double variable's address to pointer. So instead of declaring a new pointer you store its address in int type pointer then if you dereference using it, there will be a big problem and result in logical error which may get unnoticed by you if you have forgot to type cast it to double type. This is not case with void pointer. If you use void pointer, you have to compulsarily type cast it to particular type inorder to fetch data from memory. Otherwise compiler will show error. So in such cases using void pointer reminds you that you have to type cast it to proper type every time otherwise compiler will show you error. But no error will be shown in previous case

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by your opening statement: _Pointers are not having any types_? On the face of it, it is grounds for down-voting — pointer types other than `void *` are associated with a type and a `double *` is not the same as an `int *`, even if they point to the same base address.

Comment: But it is not the type of pointer, its type of data to which pointer is pointer is poonting, isnt it?

Comment: You would have to make a considerably more complex case for what you're stating than you have done.  A pointer does have a type; a variable declared by `int *ip;` is a 'pointer to `int`' and thus of a distinct type from `char *cp;` which is a 'pointer to `char`'.  Yes, object pointers do generally share the same size, but read the standard carefully; the strict reading is surprising as to which pointers are the same size and which are not.  So, I'm leaving my down-vote in place — the first paragraph grates on me and I'm not happy with the revision dated 2014-10-05 18:06:25Z.

Comment: I confess to not having fully read the rest of the answer, simply because the starting paragraph is sufficiently wrong that it renders the rest irrelevant.  I suspect that simply deleting the first paragraph would leave a decent answer, though I'm not sure that the machinations described in the last paragraph belong in an answer to someone having difficulty in the first place.